# Email Template not working

Tags: apex, email-template, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I'm trying to send an Email with an attachment and a template.

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Test Mail'];

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment tempFileAtt = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

tempFileAtt.setFileName(fileName);
tempFileAtt.setBody(pageContent);

List<String> emailIds = new List<String>();

if(emailId.contains(',')) {
    emailIds = emailId.split(',');
} else {
    emailIds.add(emailId);            
}

email.setWhatId('a0H0K00000KqqmvUAB'); //setting it to Custom Object record Id
email.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
email.setSubject(fileName);
email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
email.setToAddresses(emailIds);
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {tempFileAtt});
allmsg.add(email);

Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
```

The mail is to be sent to the Id populated in one of the custom fields. I receive an email with the correct attachment but my Email Template is missing. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The good thing is that you are receiving the email with the attachment, which means that your template does exist. Tip: query using the `DeveloperName` field, which is unique.

Comment: What kind of email template is being used? (Visualforce, HTML, Text, etc). Have you tried using the `DeveloperName` instead of the `Name` field as @RenatoOliveira suggested?

Comment: @BobLopez I'm using Text template with merge fields from my custom object. And I did try using DeveloperName, not working. The body is blank.

Comment: Could you use System.debug to see if emailTemplate.Id is filled with a value, and not null?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I am not sure that receiving the email is proof of the email template actually having been used

Comment: Hey, I solved it. WhatId cannot be used in combination with setTargetObjectId as User. It has to be a Contact.

My email template has merge fields so I'm now using my object record in WhatId and a dummy contact as TargetObject (for now).